# Image training in python

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

For an assignment in class i have to recognize a soccer ball and kick it with a NAO robot. Im still stuck in the first phase.

I already have an image of three balls next to each other. A basketball, soccer ball and beach ball. I have to use a neural network to train the robot to somehow only detect the soccer ball and kick it but don't know how to start. The code needs to be done in python.

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Please post any code you have written. It will help you garner more help.

Comment: it is completely offtopic - but what a great exercise for students! I wish my CS studies looked like this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of Python libraries that are very usefull:

1. [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/): It implements Neural Networks
2. [Scikit-Image](http://scikit-image.org/): In order to analyze images. [Here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html#example-plot-template-py) is an example about template matching. You can use a template to detect the ball (or you can detect the white pixels).

Comment: Thank you very much, so incase i want to use the neural network i should somehow convert the image to arrays that can be used as input for the neural network ?

Comment: @user3142048 Yes you should. You can use numpy to do so. Here you have an example (that doesn't use numpy) using PyBrain: http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/fnn.html